# Special character encoding issue on Solaris with weblogic server

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, solaris, special-characters, apache-fop

I have an application which uses fop and xslt to generate the PDF file. The special characters as `§£?ÐÅÆ` are appearing as `????` in PDF.

The weblogic server is running on solaris machine. 
I have already tried with

```
<charset-params>
    <input-charset>
        <resource-path>/*</resource-path>
        <java-charset-name>UTF-8</java-charset-name>
    </input-charset>
    <charset-mapping>
     <iana-charset-name>UTF-8</iana-charset-name>
    <java-charset-name>UTF-8</java-charset-name>
 </charset-mapping>     
</charset-params>
```

in `weblogic.xml`.

I have also tried with

```
transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
            transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

Nothing seems to be working over there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up fop to find fonts with those characters in?   For instance, on Solaris 11
using fop (though not with weblogic) I had to set up paths for fonts in a fop-conf.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- NOTE: This is the version of the configuration -->
<fop version="1.0">
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <fonts>
         <!-- register all the fonts found in a directory -->
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TrueType/core/</directory>
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TrueType/dejavu/</directory>
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TrueType/liberation/</directory>
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TrueType/unifont/</directory>

         <!-- register all the fonts found in a directory and all of its sub directories (use with care) -->
         <!-- directory recursive="true">C:\MyFonts2</directory -->

         <!-- automatically detect operating system installed fonts -->
         <auto-detect/>
      </fonts>
   </renderer>

   <renderer mime="application/postscript">
      <fonts>
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/</directory>
         <directory>/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts/</directory>
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TrueType/core/</directory>
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TrueType/dejavu/</directory>
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TrueType/liberation/</directory>
         <directory>/usr/share/fonts/TrueType/unifont/</directory>
      </fonts>
    </renderer>
</renderers>
</fop>
```

(Font paths will be different on older versions of Solaris.)

For more details, see:

- http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html
- http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/AddFont.html#ConfigFontFop

Comment: My server is Solaris 5.10 sparc. Will this path be ok. If not, how to get appropriate path of fonts. Also, please tell me how to provide reference to this file in my web application. Shall i need to register this file somewhere in web.xml or need to add some java code to use this.

Comment: I am new to FOP so i don't have much idea about this. I tried with fopFactory.setUserConfig(new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/xml/fo/fop-conf.xml"))); in my pdf generator class and used the above xml but this didn't worked.

Comment: FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
   fopFactory.setUserConfig(new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/xml/fo/fop-conf.xml")));
   FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();   
            foUserAgent.setBaseURL("file:///" + path);

Comment: OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF,foUserAgent, out);TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();StreamSource st = new StreamSource(servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/xml/fo/test.xsl"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(st);transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");Source src = new StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(getXML(pgmBriefId, name, dept))); Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

Comment: transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");    

    transformer.transform(src, res);

Comment: One more thing....when i created a runnable jar with the pdf generator class and xsl and tried this on the same server using.

Comment: java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar test.jar, the pdf gets generated properly with all the special characters. So, I am not getting what is going wrong with the web application.